# JQuery Mobile 1.3 Elements & Motorola Devices

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am having a issue with JQM 1.3, JQ 1.9.1, PhoneGap/Cordova 2.4.0 and the DROID RAZR 4G, MOTOROLA PHOTON 4G, MB855, DROIDX.

My issue is that the users cannot see any of the buttons, form inputs, or collapsible-sets. I can replicate the issue on browserstack.com and even FIX a part of it. I have a jsbin but if you do not have browserstack.com or a Motorola emulator, you will not be able to see the error with the link (so my description may have to do).

http://jsbin.com/ucelop/1/edit

It seems that the Motorola browser/html parser does not fully respect the z-index attribute or it is just not working well with what JQM supplies. If I change a button's z-index to 999999 I can see it in the Motorola Browser (so I guess it does respect it a bit), but this does not work for collapsible-sets and other form elements.

All my code works on every other device JQM supports. Something is up with Motorola....

Any help is greatly appreciated!

~Red

Comment: Are you aware that `z-index` only applies if an element is `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`?  Otherwise, elements are displayed in their child order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, jfriend00's comment helped steer me in the right direction.

The issue was the use of the "data-position=fixed" in the Header and Footer elements.

I was under the impression that this was fixed in JQM 1.3, but alas, it is not. Not by any fault of the JQM devs I might add, they do a super job!

On Motorola Devices, Android 4.0.4, the use of the data-position=fixed causes the overlay to hide form elements and other JQM widgets. Manually changing z-index (as I stated above) can overcome this on certain elements, however any element in which you adjust the z-index will float above the fixed footer, defeating the fixed footer effect.

While my original code worked fine on almost ALL other devices and Android versions, I could not overcome this issue.

I changed the footers to position:absolute, BUT WAIT, I still had the issue of the form elements not showing!! So I had to institute a fix from JQM site that is supposedly only for Android 2.2/2.3 and 2D CSS effects, but it fixed my issue in 4.0.4 as well.

The fix:

> When a position: fixed element appears anywhere on a page, most 2D CSS transforms will fail. Oddly, only translate transforms seem unaffected by this. Even more oddly, this issue is solved by setting a CSS opacity of .9 or below on the parent of the fixed element.

src=http://api.jquerymobile.com/fixedtoolbar/